# Cleaned Wikipedia content used on Google Maps - dump available?

Tags: google-maps, wikipedia, copyright

On Google, there are pages such as the following which provide a summary of the place in question taken from Wikipedia:

http://local.google.co.uk/maps/place?q=Canterbury+Cathedral&cid=15406428664599496982

I am not a lawyer, but I assume that as Google has obviously gone to the trouble of extracting/cleaning the data from the dump files provided by Wikipedia, this constitutes a derived work, which I think means that Google must provide the cleaned data for download.

Is providing the content online (at the link above) enough to meet that requirement, or is there a dump file of the cleaned data available somewhere?

I only need the first paragraph or two for certain Wikipedia pages, and downloading a cleaned dump from Google would save me a lot of time and trouble :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about legal issues, not about using a web application.

Comment: I have no objections. As the OP I can delete it if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a quote, and they link to the original source. I don't think they need to provide an additional download, as you can find the exact same text on wikipedia. It's not edited.

(IANAL)